# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function with remote url

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to open a Bootstrap modal window on `click` of a button. Modal window is opening a external page (same origin).

```
Please look into JS Fiddle for more clarification.

https://jsfiddle.net/deveshmishra/frubmp1y/
```

Error: When I click on button I got an error i.e.:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function.

Interesting part is that every time I didn't get this error. Sometimes it's working fine, but sometimes, it doesn't work. Another thing is that, it comes only when I load external page. Otherwise it works fine.

Comment: your bootstrap js is not being imported in your page correctly. That's why it's showing `modal` function as undefined.

Comment: That's makes sense. But for that, what is the solution ? How to ensure that bootstrap has been imported/loaded correctly on the page ?

Comment: check your browser's console first of all. That may show you a 404 error for the bootstrap js. That's a possibility only. Nonetheless, you should first check your browser console.

Comment: I checked id. When i got the error, that time browser doesn't load the bootstrap & jquery library. That's why i am getting this error. But i am unable to understand that why it's happening chrome only. Working fine in Firefox & IE.

Comment: @DeveshM, did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I just found out the problem. It's because I imported the jQuery library multiple times, when I removed one of them, the problem vanished

Comment: btw, your code works when making the script in the same page on jsfiddle link

Answer (score -1):

Problem Solved.
https://jsfiddle.net/frubmp1y/5/
Check it-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<h2>Open a Popup Window</h2>
<button id="openModal" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Bootstrap Popup</button>
```

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).on("click", "#openModal", function (){
        var url = "http://testing.dev/index.html";
        $('#myModal').modal({ show: 'true', remote: url })
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: It seems that you haven't read the error description completely. You changes are working because you are not dealing with remote url. That was already working.

Comment: Still same issue. You can test it by creating a simple index.html file with dummy content and provide the same file in remote url.

Comment: Mine is also working, but only in Fire Fox(44.0b1) & IE(11.0.9). Not working in Chrome(50.0.2661.87) only.

Comment: I am using Version 50.0.2661.94 (64-bit) of Chrome and the modal is working fine.

Comment: Let me add one more interesting thing here. Try to open the modal window and close. Repeat it few times in chrome. I am sure, you will get the error.